# When I start asp.net application this message is showing Failure to connect to web server, while till yesterday night its running well

Tags: asp.net

When I start asp.net application application is not running this message is showing "Failure to connect to web server", while till yesterday night its running well, please help.

Comment: Do you have skype on your machine as some times skype grabes port of IIS

Comment: We need more details. The iis/server is running on different machine ? Did this fail only on your web pages ? If you type the ip (not the name) is working ? Do you have ping the server to see if you get replay ? Do you have check with different browsers ? Other computers see your server or no one can connect to it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Right click on your web project

2) Select properties

3) Goto Web tab

4) Under Servers group select specific port instead of auto-assign

5) Set it to some 5 digit figure

**Alternatively:**

Sometimes Cassini can hang, so got to task manager, kill WebDev.WebServerXX.exe and try again